# My Laptop’s Motherboard Was Corroded But It Still Turns On

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, water-damage

***Long story short:*** My laptop’s motherboard got rained on but thankfully, it still turns. *Questions are at the bottom of the post*

So, my laptop *(which I just bought 4 months ago)* got rained on and it causes corrosion to my laptop’s motherboard.

I went to the service center and they showed me what happened to my laptop and how it looks like. I personally think it’s not a huge corrosion but I still want to know your thoughts.

Anyway, they told me that it’d cost me around $600 to repair my laptop. I said I’ll think about it and went home.

When I get home, I immediately put it on a rice container and planned to keep it there for 3-4 days.

My plan is to keep using it after I drain it on a rice container since I can still turn it on and I don’t have enough money to have it repaired.

*Also, just for the background:*

The laptop’s issues are some keyboard keys are not working *(backspace and enter key), and it initia*lly won’t turn on unless the charger’s plugged in ***(but it somehow got resolved when the technician at the service center looked at my unit)***.

So my questions are:

1. Is my plan okay or do I have to have the corrosion cleaned up?
2. Can I have it cleaned up on a local technicians? The service center said they can’t clean it up and they just offer replacement.
3. **Most importantly**, in the case where the motherboard really gave up. Can I still have it replaced with the new one, or will the laptop be beyond repair?

Image of the corroded motherboard:
[image: image of the corroded motherboard]

Comment: Rice is not a great humidity absorber and may be harmful. https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Don%27t_Put_Your_Device_in_Rice._Here%27s_Why... & https://www.makeuseof.com/rice-doesnt-fix-water-damage/ & 
https://www.theverge.com/2015/9/14/9326035/can-rice-actually-save-your-wet-phone & 
https://eu.usatoday.com/story/tech/2017/08/28/your-smartphone-got-wet-heres-what-do-first/609145001/ & 
https://www.wired.com/story/how-to-rescue-a-wet-phone/ & 
https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2021/apr/14/phone-wet-and-wont-turn-on-heres-what-to-do-with-water-damage-hint-putting-it-in-rice-wont-work

Comment: Which laptop do you have?

Comment: Hi @Gantendo thanks for that. I have Huawei Matebook D15 :) What else should I do to dry off the unit? The staff at the service told me that they already wiped off the water but I feel like there’s still some in it

Comment: Which model of Huawei Matebook D15?

Comment: Im not really sure but it’s i5 with 8gb ram.

Comment: here’s the processor info if needed: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1155G7 @ 2.50GHz 2.50 GHz